# cannot open jar file when create one jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have created a project and I need to create single jar with all supported library files .. but the problem is when I created using the following code the newly created jar file is not opening .. build.xml code is as follows

```
<project ...>

    <target name ="-post-jar" >
        <property name="store.jar.name" value="MarsRoverViewer"/>
        <jar jarfile="dist/JavaApplication.jar">
             <zipfileset src="lib/LICENSE4J-Library-javadoc.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/LICENSE4J-Runtime-Library.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/commons-io-2.4-javadoc.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/commons-io-2.4-sources.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/commons-math3-3.6.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/jl1.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/mp3spi-1.9.4.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/sphinx4-core-1.0-20150630.174404-9 (1).jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/sphinx4-data-1.0-20150630.174256-9 (1).jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/tritonus_mp3-0.3.6.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/tritonus_share-0.3.6.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset src="lib/vorbisspi1.0.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"/>
             <zipfileset dir="lib" includes="*."/>
             <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Home.Main"/>
             </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```